# Is the age difference between Dino and Maika in Blend S traditionally okay for romance in Japanese culture?

Tags: blend-s

As an American, it seems weird for a 26 year old to be romantically interested in a 16 year old.

http://blend-s.wikia.com/wiki/Dino

http://blend-s.wikia.com/wiki/Maika_Sakuranomiya

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "okay". Are you asking if it's legal?

Comment: Culturally acceptable. I'm aware the age of consent in Japan is 13, but a 26 year old dating a 16 year old is quite a gap.

Comment: It's common in media, but I assume you mean in actual society.

Comment: It's common in media? You could post an answer to this where you say how it's culturally acceptable in Japanese media with examples, since media technically is a part of Japanese culture.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_Asia see here.